# Finding small signal resistance for MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, resistance, small-signal

I need to find the small signal parameter \$r_{D1}\$. I understand I must draw the small signal equivalent first, but I do not know where to label this resistance, or what exactly it is equal to. Also is \$v_{dd}\$ labeled correctly?

[image: schematic]

[image: small signal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply the usual method to determine the resistance seen from two terminals, here being \$v_o\$ (gate-drain terminal) and ground. Turn off all the sources. The circuit is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwp7PJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Calculate \$i_x\$ and calculate vx/ix i.e. \$r_{d1}\$, which should be trivial.

Comment: There should be an ac signal at the bottom of ro. \$ v_{dd}\$ is not shorted in the small signal circuit.

Comment: So you're saying  \$ r_{D1}\$ is simply \$ r_{o}\$?

Comment: @Hector No, it's r0 // 1/gm

Answer (score 0):

For that circuit, with diode-tied gate-drain connection, the dynamic resistance will be the transconductance.

For long-channel FETS, the transconductance is just the derivative of Idd(Vgate), or

2 * KW/L * Ve

where K = Mobility * Cox, and Ve = Vgs = Vt

To derive this maths, write the triode-region small-signal iout(vgate) equation,
and apply your skills.

Comment: Where did you get this equation from?